# Differences between these FETs as switches

Tags: transistors

I've a conceptual question about the difference of the two following circuits in terms of functioning as switches.

The first of is the regular common source circuit, if you choose R1 wisely (?) it it possible to trigger the LED or any load at the position of LED1 both in an analog or digital way, right?

[image: common source]

The second is the simple switch with fet transistor with the load as drain resistor, this one can only be used as a digital switch, right ?

[image: fet as simple switch]

My question is : Is there a reason to use one or the other depending on the application?

Thx :)

Comment: There is no reason to use the 1st one. Its more inefficient

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 I upped your comment, because it is mostly right. But.. well... there are ***always*** reasons for choosing to use a shunt bypass. So while #1 is not so good most of the time, it is not always bad. Just mostly.

Comment: yes if limited by imagination to choose another way to make a non-inverting indicator that doesn't waste power. Assuming this is more than the average 65mW LED because you dont need  a driver if it was. Then neither would be used and if more than 150mW , that would be an inefficient light bulb or overkill for an indicator.  so I really cant think of a good use for 1st suggestion except as a bad example

Comment: There is a benefit to the shunt topology but this is more of a concern with OPTO's... So for a pure LED driver why pick it... if it is part of another question (x-y) welll

Comment: The only benefit of the first circuit is the residual leakage current from the MOSFET does not go through the LED. Granted it should be sub-microamps, but that can be significant in some cases.

Comment: The other benefit is there is an ACTIVE-on and an ACTIVE-off which means no distortion due to the LED stray capacitance. This is again an OPTO concern not a pure LED concern.

Comment: The first circuit can also minimize the current difference between LED on and LED off states, which can reduce switching noise in some very low noise situations.

Comment: I thought BJTs were better for "analog" because MOSFETs go fully on quite easily?